# 2 Way SMS using amazon SNS and Pinpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-pinpoint

I am currently able to send an SMS to a user mobile phone using AWS SNS SDK. I want to use combination of SNS for outgoing SMS and Pinpoint only for incoming SMS. I can receive a message as well using AWS Pinpoint. What I am missing currently is I am not able to correlate the outgoing and incoming messages. For e.g. When I publish to Sns I record a message Id as uuid1 and when I receive a message from Pinpoint and I look into previous message Id not same as uuid1. Is there any way to relate these two SMS using any metadata in the AWS infrastructure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not.  Text messages are stateless and there isn't really a concept of "conversations", they are just a series of messages that happen between two numbers.  You will need to create some sort of database of source/destination messages and use inbound/outbound phone numbers to correlate the messages together.